# How to decode JSON with integer as key in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift, swift4

[image]

As you can see, the right hand data has keys like "7", "8" etc...
Now I know that these are not quite "integers" because they are numbers in String.
However, **when I decode them**, **I need to use that key name as the variable name**.
But, we cannot have number as a variable name.

What should I do in this case? How can I decode this?

Is it just better to re-create the dataset so that it does not have the number as the key? But then, what do people do when they do not have control the dataset?

The entire code is too long and irrelevant so I just took a screenshot.
If you want, you can see the JSON data here
https://api.myjson.com/bins/11r19i

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4 JSON Codable ids as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333535/swift-4-json-codable-ids-as-keys)

Comment: Btw, do you know/want to know all possible bus numbers in your code? If you don't care you may just replace `[Bus]` with `[String: [MinType]]` dictionary.

Comment: check the answer @Leonard

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`CodingKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkey) to achieve that.

```
struct bus: Codable {
    var one: String?
    var two: String?
    var three: String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case one  = "1"
        case two = "2"
        case three = "3"
    }
}
```

it will decode those keys inside each `case`, you should be able to recognize now.