# How to access varying JSON key in Swift 4.2 natively?

Tags: json, swift

I have the following dummy JSON data for a bus to school.

```
{
    "toSchool": {
        "weekday": [{
            "hour": 7,
            "min": 10,
            "type": null,
            "rotary": false
        }],
        "sat": [{
            "hour": 8,
            "min": 15,
            "type": null,
            "rotary": true
        }]
    }
}
```

**I would like to access "weekday" and "sat" key with a variable based on user input. How can I achieve this natively?**

Using SwiftyJSON, it is fairly simple like below

```
let json = try JSON(data: data)
let userDirection = "shosfc"
let userWeek = "weekday"
let busList = json[userDirection][0][userWeek]
```

However, I was wondering how this would be done natively to remove dependencies.

It seems that [CodingKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codingkey) and [enum](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) might be the way to handle this. When the example is as simple as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53203040/7414387), I can understand. However, I just cannot get my head around it for my particular usage where it involves custom objects not just String.

How can I do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202948/how-to-decode-json-with-integer-as-key-in-swift-4)

```
func bus(isWeekday: Bool = true) -> [Bus] {
   return isWeekday ? shosfc.weekDay : shosfc.sat
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think code that below will work:

```
struct SampleResponse: Codable {
    let toSchool: ToSchool 
}

struct ToSchool: Codable {
    let weekday, sat: [Sat] 
}

struct Sat: Codable {
    let hour, min: Int
    let type: String?
    let rotary: Bool 
}
```

To decode this type of response, you must decode this JSON with SampleResponse type.

```
let sampleResponse = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(SampleResponse.self, from: jsonData)
```

After that, you can reach variables like you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert JSON string to Dictionary in swift and access it the same way you just did:

```swift
func parseToDictionary(_ jsonStr: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

let jsonStr = "{Your JSON String}"

let json = parseToDictionary(jsonStr)
let userDirection = "shosfc"
let userWeek = "weekday"
let busList = json[userDirection][0][userWeek]
```